# How to configure xorg.conf ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, graphics

I have some problems with the graphics settings in my Ubuntu (16.4 and now 18.4). When I see a video, in some cases my pc crashes, so I have to restart it by pressing the start button.
time ago I could solve this problem by changing the settings of the xorg.conf file, but after formatting my laptop, I lost the settings.
My OS does not have the xorg.conf file, I know it is not created by default, so I created it using the `X -configure` command in recovery mode. And this is the result for the "device" section:

```
Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
    #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
    #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
    #Option     "CustomEDID"            # <str>
    #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
    #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
    #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
    #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
    #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
    #Option     "HWRotation"            # [<bool>]
    #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
    #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
    #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
    #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
    #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
    #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
    #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
    #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
    #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
    #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
    #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
    #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "intel"
BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

And my video driver is the next one (This is the result for  `lshw -c video` command)

```
description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   phisic ID: 2
   bus information: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 0e
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:89 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f080(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Please, can you guys tell my how to configure correctly mi xorg.conf file, according mi video driver?.

thanks for advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be closed on the StackOverflow, but it would be likely ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your problem description (video generally works OK but system freezes when trying to play video) I found this suggestion for your xorg config:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "NoAccel" "True"
   Option "DRI" "False"
EndSection
```

If X is otherwise working, both your described problem and the proposed solution are consistent with the hardware video decoder not being fully supported. It's a fairly old bug report so I'm not sure if that's still the issue or if you might be running into something else.  Here's the bug report I found this in which discusses some other things you might try if this doesn't work: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1453298

Comment: Hi blihp.... This solves the first problem, although now I can see a small error in the middle of the screen, like a horizontal line that appears and disappears continuously, is it advisable to install some video driver? at least I do not have the need to restart the pc ... thanks